# how to have datalabels only on selected points

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart with several points and I want the dataLabels to appear only on those points which have been selected by the user.

I have tried several versions but it seems that the dataLabels are either on or off (There is an option to declare the datalabel in the series itself but this won't respond to select events.)

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to toggle the display of a `dataLabels`. You need to explicitly set the `dataLabels` option on each point (as far as I can tell) to false. You then add an `events` option and do this:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function () {
                    this.options.dataLabels.enabled = !this.options.dataLabels.enabled;
                    this.update();
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Here is an updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/Ccay3/). Note that if you pick anything other than the first 2 points  it fails and gives error.

Old answer which is not "dynamic":

You just enable the [`dataLabels`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels) for the points you want to have it on.
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/MH9rA/):

```
series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, {
                y: 106.4,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            },
            129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
```

Comment: Thanks but not quite what I was looking for. I need the label to exist only AFTER the user has selected the point. I guess I could use js to insert the label dynamically??

Comment: I haven't ever created a jsfiddle before, so I hope this works. Here is a link to what I am trying to do: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vveH4/2/)

Comment: Thanks! worked perfectly. You were quite right that each and every data point must have the dataLabels explicitly declared.Many thanks for your help